# Bitfinex WS flags configuration

Tags: cryptocurrency, ws

I'm creating a WS connection with Bitfinex server and sending a flag configuration event:

{
"event": "conf",
"flag": 536870912
}

as specified in https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs/ws-general#configuration, and I'm receiving

{"event":"conf","status":"OK"}

but the updates are not bulked as documented when I subscribe to Book channel. I've tried other flags and the result is similar. Is there any solutions that ensure the workout of flags feature?